# javascript and activex control communication

Tags: javascript, html, activex

I saw a website using below syntax to listen to the event from an activeX control, I am wandering where I can find the reference for the definition of the "for" and "event" keywords in "***script***" element? Is it W3C standard?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" for="DopvsPlugInCtrl" event="NotifyLocalPort(localport)">
            newport = localport;
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` and `event` attributes are **not** W3C. They are specifically designed for IE to handle ActiveX. You may take a look at this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555687).